# mysql-How to convert simple select into more complex query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this basic sql query which gets an average score and total score count for "level 1" and outputs to csv file

```
SELECT judge,AVG(score), count(judge) 
FROM results 
WHERE judge NOT LIKE '% AND %' 
  AND score >30 
  AND (class like '%1st%' OR class LIKE '%first%' OR class LIKE '%1 st%')
GROUP BY judge 
INTO OUTFILE 'c:/py/2013/all/judges-by-level.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

I want to expand this query to get average scores from multiple "levels" (derived from class column's string value) My current level 1 WHERE looks like:
(`class LIKE '%1st%' OR class LIKE '%first%' or class LIKE '%1 st%'`)
I want to change this query to get level 2, level 3 etc. using a similar LIKE
(`class LIKE '%2nd%' OR class LIKE '%second%' OR class LIKE '%2 nd%'`)

Original data looks like:

```
judge   , score  ,class
John Doe, 55.123 ,First Level Championship
Jane Doe, 65.123 ,1st Amateur Division
John Doe, 75.123 ,Second Level Championship
```

The output I am going for would be a csv file formatted like this:

```
judge, level1_avg, level1_count, level2_avg, level2_count
John Doe,55.567,123,51.123,88
Jane Doe,58.123,66,53.123,247
```

What SQL syntax would I use to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to kind of cross-tabulate based on `first/1st/1 st` and `second/2nd/2 nd`?

As a side point, the `LIKE ... OR LIKE ... OR LIKE` can be replaced by a regular expression to shorten things.

Assuming I understnd your question correctly, this should be close to what you need:

```
SELECT
  judge,
  AVG(case when class rlike '1st|first|1 st' THEN score END) level1_avg,
  COUNT(case when class rlike '1st|first|1 st' THEN judge END) level1_count,
  AVG(case when class rlike '2nd|second|2 nd' THEN score END) level2_avg,
  COUNT(case when class rlike '2nd|second|2 nd' THEN judge END) level2_count
FROM results
where judge not like '% and %' AND score > 30
group by judge
INTO OUTFILE 'c:/py/2013/all/judges-by-level.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

To take apart the `level1_avg` result column:

- If `class` contains `1st` or `first` or `1 st`, the `CASE` returns `score` so it's included in the average.
- If `class` doesn't contain `1st` or `first` or `1 st`, the `CASE` returns `null` so it's *not* included in the average.

The other aggregated columns use similar logic.

Comment: This looks really good.  Only thing I noticed is that when there is no instances for a judge in a match I need to set the value to 0 -- this is a result I need to fix: Joe Smoe,\N,0,\N,0

Comment: OK, that makes sense. In that case I'd wrap the count in a `COALESCE`, for example `COALESCE(COUNT(case when class rlike '1st|first|1 st' THEN judge END), 0) level1_count`.

Answer (score 0):

Try a union? Although this won't be efficient after so many levels. (notice the `INTO OUTFILE` and `ORDER BY` are in the final union clause)

```
SELECT judge, AVG(score) as 'level1_avg', count(judge) as 'level1_count', '' as 'level2_avg', '' as 'level2_count', '' as 'level3_avg', '' as 'level3_count'  
FROM results 
WHERE judge NOT LIKE '% AND %' 
   AND score >30 
   AND (class like '%1st%' OR class LIKE '%first%' OR class LIKE '%1 st%')
GROUP BY judge

UNION ALL

SELECT judge, '' as 'level1_avg', '' as 'level1_count', AVG(score) as 'level2_avg', count(judge) as 'level2_count', '' as 'level3_avg', '' as 'level3_count'
FROM results 
WHERE judge NOT LIKE '% AND %' 
   AND score >30 
   AND (class like '%2nd%' OR class LIKE '%second%' OR class LIKE '%2 nd%')
GROUP BY judge    

UNION ALL

SELECT judge, '' as 'level1_avg', '' as 'level1_count', '' as 'level2_avg', '' as 'level2_count', AVG(score) as 'level3_avg', count(judge) as 'level3_count' 
   INTO OUTFILE 'c:/py/2013/all/judges-by-level.csv'
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
FROM results 
WHERE judge NOT LIKE '% AND %' 
   AND score >30 
   AND (class like '%3rd%' OR class LIKE '%third%' OR class LIKE '%3 rd%')
GROUP BY judge   
ORDER BY judge
```

**EDIT**: added blanks in the appropiate columns in the union

Comment: this looks interesting, but repeats value for judge.  I am looking for a cross tabulation Thanks a lot!